# Remove the Material Stepper header

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to get rid of the header navigation on the material stepper. Please suggest how can I do it?
I tried setting the following css but didn't seems to work:

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container{display: none}
```

Here is stackblitz link of the stepper.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-ybbnhe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `::ng-deep` to get around shadow DOM and the `!important` flag to get around Materials own stylings:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: But it still stays in the dom. This is not an ideal solution. Just saying, I don't know a better one.

Comment: Adding !important to the css is bad practice, because the important styles are rendered after the original once. That causes browser to render the html element twice. My advice is to use:
```css
:host ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@Simon K answer is correct. But it will affect all the stepper in your app. But if you want to use it for your specific component, use `:host` before the `::ng-deep`. Then it will not affect other stepper (if any) in your application. For example of @Simon K' answer-

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Extend CSS and **use additional attribute** on the  element to hide just specific use-case of it.

```
mat-stepper[hide-header] .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display:none;
}
```

```
<mat-stepper hide-header orientation="horizontal" #stepper>
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code is working for hide the mat stepper header.
`:host ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container { display: none !important; }`

Comment: This answer has already been provided and is a duplicate.

Answer (score -7):

you can add this css property in `<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>` like this:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper style="display: none;">
....
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: That removes the content of the stepper also. I only want to remove the top navigation.