# How to hide mat-stepper header in my mat-stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developing an application using Angular-7. In the application, I used Angular material's `mat stepper`. The question is, how do I hide `mat-stepper` header as highlighted in the diagram below. I don't want it to appear at all.

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <mat-step label="transaction">
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="personal">
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

[image: stepper diagram]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the Material Stepper header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716812/remove-the-material-stepper-header)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ngIf` to achieve this. If you want to hide a particular `mat-step` then, place the `ngIf` on the `mat-step`.

```html
<mat-step label="transaction" *ngIf="showStep">
    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
</mat-step>
```

If you want to get rid of the entire `mat-horizontal-stepper`, then place the `ngIf` on the `<mat-horizontal-stepper>`

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper *ngIf="showStepper">
```

where you can update the value of `showStep` or `showStepper` to `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to show the stepper or not.

> Note: This will remove the content as well.

If you want to remove just the `mat-horizontal-stepper` headers and keep the content, then you can do so using CSS.

```css
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: when I added  <mat-step label="transaction" *ngIf="showStep">  as you advised the all the buttons (previous and next) did not display again. I only want to hide the label and icon.  Can you show me a sample with my code?

Comment: @ nash11  -  where do I add   .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    display: none !important;
}

Comment: Add it to your component's styles. If your component uses a css file for styles, then put it in that file.

Comment: To hide the header, in your component styles use:

```:host ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display: none;
}```

Comment: @TodorTodorov Thanks, Here is the SCSS version that may help someone 
`:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}`